# Nearline SAS on SATA controllers

Tags: sata, sas, controller

I know that SAS drives cannot operate on a SATA controller.
I know that SATA drives can operate on a SAS controller.

But can Near-Line SAS drives, being SATA drives with a SAS controller, be used on
A) only SAS controllers
B) both SATA and SAS controllers
?

Note that the nearline SAS drives feature "dual port", but I'm unsure if this means "has a SATA and a SAS port" or "has 2 SAS ports". Especially since I seem to read that the connnectors and cables themselves seem to be interchangeable, which, if they are, would make the dual port conundrum moot.

Comment: Based on your comment to Chopper3, it sounds like you really want reliable SATA disks. Both Seagate and Western Digital have "Enterprise SATA" models, that feature some more advanced features; better reliability specifications; higher duty cycles; and larger capacities than regular desktop drives. Look for Seagate Constellation ES or Western Digital Raid Edition (RE) drives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I know that SATA drives can operate on a SAS controller" - you may know many popular SAS controllers than *can* run SATA disks but don't make this assumption, there's nothing in the SAS specs that state they *should* also run SATA disks, they just share a lot of common features (connectors/cabling etc.). Manufacturers can pick and choose to do as they wish.

Now your question - no this won't work, it's the SAS signalling that's different, so no SATA-only controllers won't be able to work with any SAS disks at all. Also again it's an assumption of yours that all near-line drives are SATA with a SAS controller - that's not the case, it's the controller that defines the protocol used. Near-line SAS disks are just disks, there's nothing inherently SATA-oriented about them, they then have a SAS controller attached to them.

Dual-porting is a SAS feature that allows a single disk to have two physical SAS links out of its controller, this is usually used to allow for diverse electrical paths but can be used to connect a single disk to two controllers to better handle hardware failure. It's got nothing to do with SATA at all.

Comment: Note that I have 0 experience in SAS. I'm looking at ordering a budget server (really for home purposes) and wondering what level of enterpriseyness (is that a word?) I can incorporate taking into account that I may need to attach the drives to a consumer machine at a later date. But thank you for your info.

Comment: If you want 'enterprise' features go for a Xeon E3 or 56xx-series CPU, use their triple-memory-channel capability, team your NICs and get a machine that has the capacity for dual power supplies. It's the resilience and linearity of performance fall-off that differentiates a server, not just the outright unloaded 'power'. I love SAS/FC/FCoE and it's while it's important to have multiple controllers and paths on a server performance is secondary to stability.

Comment: This isn't a production server that needs 99.9% uptime. If I'm out of business for 2 or 3 days it's no biggy. For me performance matters and good, frequent backups. I agree, when my business gets beyond "mudding about after hours", stability will pop up headfirst (like it does at my clients). Good advice as well :)

Answer (score 3):

NL-SAS drives have the mechanical characteristics of 'enterprise' SATA drives, with SAS controllers - this is mostly in terms of reliability/endurance/error rates/etc.  They're not electronically sata on the controller side of things, with a SAS bridge - they're SAS all the way.

But, to answer your question specifically, no you cannot connect a NL-SAS disk to a SATA controller.

To answer some of the other post here, many controllers will allow you to connect SATA disks to a SAS controller, but many raid cards will not let you mix SAS and SATA in a virtual disk pool - NL-SAS could, but at possibly a significant degradation in services.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation of what NL-SAS internally is was how I preceived it to be. You just worded it best of all :).